# Angular directive's element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have this directive:

```
function dndDirective($timeout) {

  return {
    template: '<div class="dndComponent"> Title: {{title}} </div>',
    scope: {
      title: '<'
    },
    compile: myCompile
  };

      function myCompile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        return {
          pre: function postLink($scope, element, attrs, transclude) {

            $scope.$watchGroup(['title'], function(newVals) {
              $timeout(function() {
                jQuery('.dndComponent').first().myPlugin();
                jQuery(element).myPlugin();
              });
            })
          }
        }
      }
```

Why is `jQuery('.dnd').first()` a different object than `jQuery(element)`? They have different contexts and my jQuery plugin can only work with the first option.

Comment: The second argument of the postLink function

Comment: `jQuery('.dnd')` will find the first element anywhere in page with that class. Not enough known beyond that

Comment: That's not explaining what element is. What's the html?

Comment: ^^ note that should say `jQuery('.dnd').first()` as in question

Comment: @JoeyWood the html is in the directive's declaration `template` field

Comment: your first line is looking for class `'.dnd'`, but your template has class     `dndComponent`

Comment: @JoeyWood you're right, thanks. I'll fix the question since that is not really the problem

Comment: What is `jquery(element)` returning?

Comment: `jQuery(element)` returns `[my-component.ng-isolate-scope, selector: "", context: my-component.ng-isolate-scope]` and `jQuery('.dnd')` returns `[div.div.my-component.my-class, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".dnd"]`

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(element)` returns a jQuery wrapper of the element where the directive is being used.
`jQuery('.dndComponent').first()` returns the first element with that class.

Assuming the directive is being only used once (do not rely on this), the selector is returning a child of `element`, `element` is the parent of '.dndComponent';

===

Consider also doing $(element).find('.dndComponent') because this way you can use your directive N times and it will always work, otherwise it will always return the `.dndComponent` of the first directive.